# Basic SQLite3 query: finding highest score

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

It outputs the list of classes once and then a max score of 100 for all classes. There's a max score of 100 for 2 classes in my table, BUT not the other 4. So, why would it be printing out the max score for one class for all classes? e.g. all classes should not have a max score of 100, but the max score that was actually attained in each class.

Comment: Max(t.score) will select the highest score from the entire table, not the highest score from that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOINS are missing in your sql

```
SELECT C.crsid, MAX(TC.score) as maxscore
FROM Class C
JOIN ClassSection CS
on C.crsid = CS.crsid
JOIN TookClass TC
on TC.secid = CS.secid
GROUP BY C.crsid
order by maxscore desc;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Is there a way to do without joins for future reference?